# shell programming (shell command usage)

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

1. PWD=$(shell pwd)
2. PLAT_NAME ?= Z22

The statements are used as part of makefile. Please explain below query
In Q1.  what does the shell mean? . Is this a shell command?
In Q2.  what does ?= means?

Comment: 'Q1', 'Q2', is this homework? Also: Only one question per question please. Also: If you're pasting homework here, atleast take care to format it for those who are helping you.

Answer (score 3):

`$(shell ...)` is the [shell function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) which is used to execute a system command.  So `$(shell pwd)`, executes the `pwd` command.

`?=` is the conditional variable assignment operator and is used to assign a value to a variable if the variable is not already defined. Specifically, `PLAT_NAME ?= Z22` sets the variable `PLAT_NAME` to `Z22` if `PLAT_NAME` has not already been set.

See the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for more information.